# How do you set the Focus to an embedded YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, embedding

I'm using YouTube's JavaScript API to embed a video onto my personal site. I would like to be able to set the focus directly on the seek bar of the embedded YouTube video to allow the use of the keyboard shortcuts when the page loads.

I've been trying the `.focus()` option but haven't had any luck.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var done = false;
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '500',
      width: '820',
      videoId: 'k-sfFFnfO8g',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      }
    });

}

function onPlayerReady(evt) {
    evt.target.playVideo();
    evt.target.pauseVideo();
    document.getElementById('script').focus();
}
```

Any suggestions or help?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear